# Create a table with multi row and merged cell

Tags: tables

I would like to have a table to looks like this:

[image]

I have referred to the existing questions a lot.

I couldn't express this type of table.

The C, D, and E parts are too difficult for me.

Comment: Try https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb Wow!!! It's so awesome!! really thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a combination of `\multirow` and `\multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multirow{2}{*}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multirow{2}{*}{F}  \\
\cline{3-4}
                   &                    & D      & E            &                 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```